# Why am I getting terrible precision using SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm training an AI to recognize parasite eggs using Suport Vector Machine, but its predictions are basically random. I've tried changing many parameters, but it doesn't solve the problem.

The python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import re

categories = {
            0: "Ascaris lumbricoides",
            1:"Capillaria philippinensis",
            2: "Enterobius vermicularis",
            3: "Fasciolopsis buski",
            4: "Hookworm egg",
            5: "Hymenolepis diminuta",
            6: "Hymenolepis nana",
            7: "Opisthorchis viverrine",
            8: "Paragonimus spp",
            9: "Taenia spp. egg",
            10: "Trichuris trichiura"
        }
categories_inverse = {}
for k,v in categories.items():
    categories_inverse[v] = k 

#processing training images

flat_data_arr=[] #input array
target_arr=[] #output array

#path which contains all the categories of images
for entry in os.scandir('/home/fernandomorais/FernandoMorais/parasitos/Chula-ParasiteEgg-11/Chula-ParasiteEgg-11/imagensNormais/images'):

    (name, extension) = os.path.splitext(entry.name)
    #Erases the number in front of the parasite's name
    #Example: Ascaris lumbricoides_0001 -> Ascaris lumbricoides
    name = name[:-5] 

    img_array=imread(entry.path)
    img_resized=resize(img_array,(300,300,3))
    flat_data_arr.append(img_resized.flatten())
    target_arr.append(categories_inverse[name])
 
flat_data=np.array(flat_data_arr)
target=np.array(target_arr)
df_treino=pd.DataFrame(flat_data) 
df_treino['Target']=target


flat_data_arr=[] #input array
target_arr=[] #output array

for entry in os.scandir('/home/fernandomorais/FernandoMorais/parasitos/Chula-ParasiteEgg-11_test/imagensPrincipais/imagensNormais/images'):
    try:

        (name, extension) = os.path.splitext(entry.name)

        path_label = os.path.join("/home/fernandomorais/FernandoMorais/parasitos/Chula-ParasiteEgg-11_test/imagensPrincipais/imagensNormais/labels",name+".txt")
        with open(path_label) as file:
            target_arr.append(int(file.readline().split()[0]))
        img_array=imread(entry.path)
        img_resized=resize(img_array,(300,300,3))
        flat_data_arr.append(img_resized.flatten())
    except:
        pass

flat_data=np.array(flat_data_arr)
target=np.array(target_arr)
df_test=pd.DataFrame(flat_data) 
df_test['Target']=target

x_train = df_treino.iloc[:,:-1]
y_train = df_treino.iloc[:,-1]
x_test = df_test.iloc[:,:-1]
y_test = df_test.iloc[:,-1]


for c in [1]:
    svc = svm.SVC(probability=True)
    param_grid={'C':[c],
                'kernel':['rbf'],
                'max_iter':[1000] }
    # Creating a model using GridSearchCV with the parameters grid
    model=GridSearchCV(svc,param_grid)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)

    # Testing the model using the testing data
    y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
    
    # Calculating the accuracy of the model
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
    
    # escreve the accuracy of the model
    escreve(f"The model is {accuracy*100}% accurate")

    escreve(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=list(categories.values())))
    escreve(" ")
```

Output:

```
The model is 8.636363636363637% accurate
                           precision    recall  f1-score   support

     Ascaris lumbricoides       0.00      0.00      0.00        47
Capillaria philippinensis       0.04      0.09      0.06        34
  Enterobius vermicularis       0.08      0.13      0.10        46
       Fasciolopsis buski       0.00      0.00      0.00        34
             Hookworm egg       0.12      0.18      0.14        34
     Hymenolepis diminuta       0.10      0.39      0.16        46
         Hymenolepis nana       0.00      0.00      0.00        40
   Opisthorchis viverrine       0.00      0.00      0.00        41
          Paragonimus spp       0.06      0.07      0.06        43
          Taenia spp. egg       1.00      0.06      0.11        35
      Trichuris trichiura       0.00      0.00      0.00        40

                 accuracy                           0.09       440
                macro avg       0.13      0.08      0.06       440
             weighted avg       0.12      0.09      0.06       440
```

I've already tried using c values from 100 to 0.001 and the results are basically the same.
Is there something I'm doing wrong in the code?

Comment: In your own words, **why should the training data be sufficient** to train a model with any accuracy? We can't see that data, so there's no way we could possibly verify that. This is kind of a general problem with AI questions; we can only really approach them from the angle of "is there a concrete flaw in the code?", rather than the overall approach or design. You may find that better answers are available on [ai.se].

Answer (score 2):

SVMs are sensitive to the scaling of the features - the features should be standardised to be roughly on the same scale.

Ensure your training data `x_train` is an array of shape `samples x features (pixels)`, then fit a scaler and use to scale the training and test data:

```
#Fit scaler
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)

#Apply to training and test data
train_data_scaled = scaler.transform(x_train)
test_data_scaled = scaler.transform(x_test)
```

This will transform the ranges of each pixel to be on similar scales.

Some other trouble-shooting tips when the model isn't learning:

- Initially, try to simply overfit the training data to ensure the model can learn. Do this by reducing the training set down to a small number (and optionally using large `C`, as this gives the model freedom to overfit). The *train* score should be high as you've made it easy for the model to simply memorize some training samples. If the train score is low, something else is wrong.
- Once you can overfit some training data, you know the model's able to learn, and you can work from there to a better-tuned model.

Comment: OP is doing grid search so it would be better to put the scaler in a pipeline and do the grid search on that (otherwise the scaled data is split in every k-fold validation set).